# How to enable package caching in dnf?

Tags: networking, fedora, package-management, cache, dnf

I started using fedora 22 and started learning dnf only to find out about two annoying facts:

- *Almost* every time I install or upgrade anything it has to rebuild the whole repository metadata cache all over.
- If I stopped the download of packages at 99% and re-ran the install command it would download them all over again! This is really annoying because I have a slow internet connection that drops every half an hour or so (It's an rtl8723be module, does anybody have a fix ?), so dnf essentialy becomes unusable.

How can I resolve that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the keepcache parameter. I believe that it goes in /etc/dnf/dnf.conf and should read keepcache=1 or keepcache="true"

Answer (score 1):

This command creates metadata cache for downloads:

```
sudo dnf makecache
```

To instruct `dnf` to be more resource-aware and to terminate immediately if it’s too soon after the last successful `makecache` run we add timer to it:

```
sudo dnf makecache timer
```

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 26 here.

> If I stopped the download of packages at 99% and re-ran the install command it would download them all over again! ...

That is what I thought at first, but I'm installing a great number of packages with "dnf" at the moment, and something seems to be a little bit off about how the partially successful downloads are accounted for in the status bar.  If the files are available by FTP, a "reget" command may be issued to resume a partial download, even from a different mirror, or by HTTP arbitrary byte ranges may be requested for the missing portion of a partially downloaded file.